# how to change ascii alphabet to utf-8 in php

Tags: php, utf-8

I have an ASCII string. I like to change its encoding to utf-8.
But I found there's a simple function to change ascii to utf-8 in php.
and vice verse, I like to change utf-8 alphabet to ascii.
Please advise.

I have tried:

```
<?php
// utf-8
$str = "ＣＨＯＮＫＩＯＫ";  
// I can't even how to print these utf-8 characters in php. I just copied/pasted the string. 
// strlen($str) => 24 bytes
// mb_detect_encoding($str) => utf-8

$str2 = "CHONKIOK";
// strlen($str2) => 8 bytes
// mb_detect_encoding($str2) => ascii

// change ascii to utf-8
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str2, "UTF-8");

echo mb_detect_encoding($str);
// returns ascii
```

Comment: ASCII is already valid UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is correct.
As per [mb_detect_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) it states that it detects the **most likely** character encoding.

As the entire ASCII set is contained within UTF-8 at the exact same character positions, this function is telling you that it's an ASCII string because *it technically is*. The bytes of this string when encoded in both ASCII and UFT-8 are identical.

As you've found, when you include some characters outside of the ASCII set then it will give you the next probable encoding.

**What exactly should I do to obtain this string: "ＣＨＯＮＫＩＯＫ" from "CHONKIOK"?**

The characters you're after are called "Fullwidth Latin" characters.

Given the `Ｃ` character provided is character 65,315 and a regular `C` is character 67, you could possible obtain the strings you're after by adding the difference of 65,248. This is only possible because the alphabet tends to repeat in the same order throughout different parts of the character charts.

You can get the code point of a character using [mb_ord](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ord.php) and convert it back to a character using [mb_chr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-chr.php), after adding 65,248.

That might look something like:

```
$str_input = "ABC abc 123";
$convertable = "ABCDEFG12349abcdefg";
$str_output = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str_input); $i++) {
    $char = mb_ord($str_input[$i], "UTF-8");
    if(str_contains($convertable, $str_input[$i])) $char += 65248;
    $str_output .= mb_chr($char, "UTF-8");
}

echo $str_output;  // outputs "ＡＢＣ ａｂｃ １２３"
```

Just be sure to include the whole alphabet in `$convertable`

Comment: What exactly should I do to obtain this string: "ＣＨＯＮＫＩＯＫ" from "CHONKIOK"?

Comment: I doubt OP wants only Fullwidth Latin characters converted.

Comment: That's why I put it a kind of separate answer with the question in bold, OP asked this question right above your comment.

Comment: I think the code commented "I can't even how to print these utf-8 characters in PHP" is perhaps the goal they were after and asking about UTF-8 was a red herring

Comment: I still don't fully understand your explanation.. but your code works well. I'm gonna have to look into your code. Thanks a million. You made my day!!!!

Comment: Ultimately its just looking at each letter and if its in the list of letters to convert, then adding a fixed character offset (65248) to get the "Fullwidth Latin" version of that letter in the unicode charts.

Answer (score -2):

try this to convert to utf-8:

```
utf8_encode(string $string): string
```

try this to convert to ASCII:

```
utf8_decode(string $string): string
```

Comment: This makes "????????".

Comment: This functions convert from/to ISO-8859-1, which is completely different from ASCII.